# Why does C++ allow std::initializer_list to be coerced to primitive types, and be used to initialise them?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

This question is regarding std::initializer_list, and why it is allowed to initialise primitive types. Consider the following two functions:

```
void foo(std::string arg1, bool arg2 = false);
void foo(std::string arg1, std::deque<std::string> arg2, bool arg3 = false);
```

Why is it that, when calling foo like this:

```
foo("some string", { });
```

The first overload is picked, instead of the second? Well, actually not *why* it's picked, it's because `{ }` can be used to initialise *anything*, including primitive types. My question is the reasoning behind this.

std::initializer_list takes `{ args... }`, and as such cannot have indeterminate length at the time of compilation. Attempting to do something like `bool b = { true, true }` gives `error: scalar object 'b' requires one element in initialiser`.

While it might have seemed like a good idea to allow uniform initialisation, the fact is that this is confusing and entirely unexpected behaviour. Indeed, how is the compiler able to do this, without some magic in the background doing std::initializer_list things?

Unless `{ args... }` is a C++ lexical construct, in which case my point still stands: why is it allowed to be used in the initialisation of primitive types?

Thanks. I had quite the bug-hunting session here, before realising that the wrong overload was being called. Spent 10 minutes figuring out why.

Comment: `{}` is a *braced-init-list*; it has no type. `std::initializer_list` Is a different thing.

Comment: I don't know how interested you are in this, but the first is picked because `{}` -> `bool` is the identity conversion and `{}` -> `std::deque<std::string>` is a user-defined conversion sequence. `arg3` does not play a role in overload resolution and the `bool arg2 = false` parameter is treated like `bool arg2` because there are two arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That `{}` syntax is a *braced-init-list*, and since it is used as an argument in a function call, it *copy-list-initializes* a corresponding parameter.

§ 8.5 [dcl.init]/p17:

> <sup>(17.1)</sup> — If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).

§ 8.5.4 [dcl.init.list]/p1:

> *List-initialization* is initialization of an object or reference from a *braced-init-list*. Such an initializer is
>   called an *initializer list*, and the comma-separated initializer-clauses of the list are called the elements of the
>   initializer list. An initializer list may be empty. *List-initialization* can occur in *direct-initialization* or *copy-initialization* contexts; [...]

For a class-type parameter, with list-initialization, overload resolution looks up for a viable constructor in two phases:

§ 13.3.1.7 [over.match.list]/p1:

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor
>   in two phases:
>
> — Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
>
> — If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

but:

> If the initializer list has no elements and `T` has a default constructor, the first phase is omitted.

Since `std::deque<T>` defines a non-explicit default constructor, one is added to a set of viable functions for overload resolution. Initialization through a constructor is classified as a **user-defined conversion** (§ 13.3.3.1.5 [over.ics.list]/p4):

> Otherwise, if the parameter is a non-aggregate class `X` and overload resolution per 13.3.1.7 chooses a single
>   best constructor of `X` to perform the initialization of an object of type `X` from the argument initializer list,
>   the implicit conversion sequence is a user-defined conversion sequence with the second standard conversion
>   sequence an identity conversion.

Going further, an empty braced-init-list can value-initialize its corresponding parameter (§ 8.5.4 [dcl.init.list]/p3), which for literal types stands for zero-initialization:

> <sup>(3.7)</sup> — Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.

This, for literal types like `bool`, doesn't require any conversion and is classified as a **standard conversion** (§ 13.3.3.1.5 [over.ics.list]/p7):

> Otherwise, if the parameter type is not a class:
>
> <sup>(7.2)</sup> — if the initializer list has no elements, the implicit conversion sequence is the identity conversion.
>
> [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> void f(int);
> f( { } );
> // OK: identity conversion
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

Overload resolution checks in first place if there exists an argument for which a conversion sequence to a corresponding parameter is better than in another overload (§ 13.3.3 [over.match.best]/p1):

> [...] Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a better function than another viable function
>   `F2` if for all arguments `i`, `ICSi(F1)` is not a worse conversion sequence than `ICSi(F2)`, and then:
>
> <sup>(1.3)</sup> — for some argument `j`, `ICSj(F1)` is a better conversion sequence than `ICSj(F2)`, or, if not that, [...]

Conversion sequences are ranked as per § 13.3.3.2 [over.ics.rank]/p2:

> When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as defined in 13.3.3.1)
>
> <sup>(2.1)</sup> — a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence, and [...]

As such, the first overload with `bool` initialized with `{}` is considered as a better match.

Comment: I'm always confused in which order the subsections of overload resolution apply, but I think all important aspects for the OP are now in your answer. Though I still don't quite understand *why* the committee has classified *`{}` -> class type* as a user-defined conversion.

Comment: Alright, I'm accepting this as the answer; it's the most complete and thorough.

Either way though, thanks all you guys for the input. I get it now, uniform initialisation list != std::initialiser_list.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `{}` does not actually indicate an `std::initializer_list`. It is also used for uniform initialization. Uniform initialization was intended to fix the problems of the piles of different ways C++ objects could be initialized but ended up just making things worse, and the syntactic conflict with `std::initializer_list` is fairly awful.

Bottom line is that `{}` to denote an `std::initializer_list` and `{}` to denote uniform initialization are two different things, except when they're not.

> Indeed, how is the compiler able to do this, without some magic in the
>   background doing std::initialiser_list things?

The aforementioned magic most assuredly exists. `{ args... }` is simply a lexical construct and the semantic interpretation depends on context- it is certainly not an `std::initializer_list`, unless the context says it is.

> why is it allowed to be used in the initialisation of primitive types?

Because the Standards Committee did not properly consider how broken it was to use the same syntax for both features.

Ultimately, uniform init is broken by design, and should realistically be banned.

Comment: This isn't accurate, `{ }` is always an _initializer list_ (see [dcl.init.list]) but that's not the same as `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: That... is simply an unfortunate way that the constructs are named. I meant to refer to `std::initializer_list`. It hadn't occurred to me that the lexical construct was *also* called an `initializer list`.

Comment: It's not just coincidence, and "initializer list" is a semantic construct not just a grammar term. The class template `std::initializer_list` is the utility that allows you to capture an initializer list and treat it as a first class object. Some initializer lists get converted into a `std::initializer_list` object, but not all do, some just perform initialization directly, e.g. by invoking a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is the reasoning behind this.

The reasoning behind it is simple (albeit flawed). List-initialization initializes everything.
In particular, `{}` stands for "default" initializing the object it corresponds to; Whether this means that its `initializer_list`-constructor is called with an empty list, or that its default constructor is called, or that it is value-initialized, or that all of an aggregates subobjects are initialized with `{}`, etc. is irrelevant: It is supposed to act as a universal initializer for any object that the above can be applied to.

If you wanted to call the second overload, you'd have to pass e.g. `std::deque<std::string>{}` (or pass three arguments in the first place). That is the current modus operandi.

> While it might have seemed like a good idea to allow uniform
>   initialisation, the fact is that this is confusing and entirely
>   unexpected behaviour.

I wouldn't call it "entirely unexpected" by any means. What is confusing about list-initializing primitive types? It is absolutely vital for aggregates - but there's not that big of a step from aggregate types to arithmetic ones, as no `initializer_list` is involved in both cases. Don't forget that it can e.g. be useful to prevent narrowing as well.

> `std::initialiser_list` takes `{ args... }`, and as such cannot have
>   indeterminate length at the time of compilation.

Well, technically speaking,

```
std::initializer_list<int> f(bool b) {
    return b? std::initializer_list<int>{} : std::initializer_list<int>{1};
}
```

Comment: I don't get why ***uniform** initialization* prefers to initialize non-class types when the list is empty. Especially since [over.ics.list]p2 can rank list-init of class types as an *identity conversion*. This has been introduced by [CWG 1467](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/6513c26cc9af918377ebc8733e57bc3e3d48d963), which has also revised the dcl.init.list wording. OTOH, [CWG 1301](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/7eed4036396d73f7c75719808119d993e840ce8c) only revised the dcl.init.list wording but not over.ics.list. Why?

Comment: @dyp Perhaps simplicity. Overload resolution prefers a simple scalar initialization to a function (constructor) call?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Initializing a class type with a trivial default ctor via `{}` won't call a ctor at all, which makes [over.ics.list]p6 sound strange IMO. It looks more like this case is just missing. I'll try to find something in the proposals tomorrow (haven't found relevant DRs), otherwise I'll ask std-discussion.

Comment: @dyp Yep. I was also wondering why vacuous initialization wasn't handled specially there. I would definitely prefer bool to deque, but I certainly wouldn't be that sure about bool vs some type where value-initialization implies zero-init. Let me know about any papers.